# How to eliminate duplication of Play Framework Json formatting code of AnyVals in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I use AnyVals extensively to ensure type safety in my code and make it more expressive. I'm also often required to translate my objects to/from Json using the Play Framework API. I've ended up with many near-duplicated lines that look something like this:

```
protected implicit val capabilityFormats: Format[SomeId] =
    implicitly[Format[String]].inmap(SomeId.apply, _.value)

protected implicit val capabilityFormats: Format[FullName] =
    implicitly[Format[String]].inmap(FullName.apply, _.value)

protected implicit val capabilityFormats: Format[CityName] =
    implicitly[Format[String]].inmap(CityName.apply, _.value)

protected implicit val capabilityFormats: Format[StreetName] =
    implicitly[Format[String]].inmap(StreetName.apply, _.value)
```

Intuitively, it seems like since I know each of these classes has:

- a .value: String member, and
- an .apply(value: String) constructor, that

I should be able to do this with a trait or something.

I can get it to work for Writes[], since I can inherit the trait which includes the .value: String member, but I don't know how to let the compiler know that there's a trivial way to go from a String to the class it is looking for.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk My team pretty much just uses play-json